# Linear representations of compact groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, locally-compact-groups

I was reading about linear representations of compact groups in the book of Jean-Pierre Serre: "Linear Representations of Finite Groups", and he states that most of the properties for representations of finite groups carry over to representations of compact groups, but i didn't understand why those properties are valid specific in compact groups, but not in any kind of infinite groups.

My understanding was because in compact groups we can replace the expressions "$(1/g)(\sum_{g \in G} f(t)$" by "$\int_G f(t) dt$" and by doing so, we can carry over the results of finite group representations, is that right?

To give some context in my knowledge: i don't have a strong background in measure theory and topology yet.

Comment: There is a lot to elaborate on this, so it would be better if you have a more specific question.

Comment: I wanted an example to why can't those properties carry over to any kind of infinite group.
My understanding was because in compact groups we can replace the expressions "$(1/g)(\sum_{g \in G} f(t)$" by "$\int_G f(t) dt$" and by doing so, we can carry over the results of finite group representations, is that right?

Comment: The group averaging trick makes things easy in the compact case and if the group is abelian, you know the dual group is discrete which is also fairly easy to analyze. In locally compact abelian groups, things get tough because you can get all sorts of bizarre behavior. You should read up on this instead of asking a very vague question. You're basically asking for a full run down of a very active area of math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other commenters have pointed out, this is a very broad question. However here is one aspect of where the finite-dimensional representation theory of compact groups mirrors finite groups: semisimplicity of representations.

Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex representation of a finite group $G$, so we have a homomorphism $\rho_V \colon G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$. One way to prove that $V$ is semisimple is to put a $G$-invariant inner product on $V$. We can do that by taking *any* inner product $H \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ and averaging it over the group: define a new inner product $\langle -, - \rangle \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ by the formula
$$ \langle u, v \rangle = \sum_{g \in G} H(\rho_V(g) u, \rho_V(g) v). $$
Then you can check that this is indeed an inner product, and that each operator $\rho_V(g)$ acts by unitary transformations under the new inner product, and therefore whenever we have a subrepresentation $U \subseteq V$ the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ is also a subrepresentation, with $U \oplus U^\perp = V$. (Everything above also works for real representations).

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex representation of a compact group $G$, then you can do exactly the same thing, replacing the sum over group elements with an integral over the group using the Haar measure. The fact that the Haar measure is translation-invariant means that the new inner product $\langle -, - \rangle$ makes the operators $\rho_V(g)$ unitary, and so again representations are semisimple.

This does not work for groups that are not compact. For example, take the Lie group $G = (\mathbb{R}, +)$, and consider the representation into $2 \times 2$ matrices
$$ \rho \colon \mathbb{R} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}), \quad t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$
We can see that $\rho$ is not semisimple, since it contains a subrepresentation spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ but no complementary subrepresentation.